# How to change the font-lock string definition?

Tags: major-mode, font-lock

I wrote a simple mode with the following `font-lock` definition, which defines just some keywords:

```
(defvar marpa-mode-font-lock
  `((,(regexp-opt '(":default" "action" "lexeme" "default" "latm" "separator") t)
     . 'font-lock-keyword-face)
    )
  "Highlighting for Marpa mode")
```

I use it in my mode function in this way:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(marpa-mode-font-lock))
```

When I use the mode more than just the keywords are highlighted. Strings are also highlighted with some kind of C or Lisp default syntax.

How can I disable the default string syntax in order to replace it with my own definition?

In the language for which I wrote the mode, strings are not delimited by double quotes. Instead they are delimited by single quotes and may have a suffix attribute like this: `'create':i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings and comments are highlighted based on the information in the syntax table.

Typically, this is much better than a keyword-based solution as it handles multi-line constructs better.

However, if you really want to disable this, you can set `font-lock-keywords-only`:

> font-lock-keywords-only is a variable defined in `font-lock.el'.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means Font Lock should not fontify comments or strings.
>   This is normally set via `font-lock-defaults'.

Comment: I see. I have *stolen* the syntax-table modification from `sql-mode`: `(modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" table)` and `(modify-syntax-entry ?\" "." table)`. There seems to be no way to make the suffix also part of the string?

Comment: @ceving, can you give me some concrete examples on what is a correct string and something that incorrectly is highlighted as one. (I don't know sql).

Comment: I think [i got it](https://github.com/ceving/marpa-mode); btw nice piece of software your [el2markdown](https://github.com/Lindydancer/el2markdown).